# How to have conveniently bootable snapshot recovery point on Windows?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, backup

I want to set up a computer, so that I can have, say, weekly backup of the whole OS & files. This way if part of the OS is corrupted by an **encryption virus**, I want an easy way to **simply reboot to the last clean backup**.

I'm thinking maybe some kind of Host or Parent OS, perhaps non-Windows which manages various Virtual Hard Drives.

The problem with backup up to an external drive is a) it takes a long time to copy a whole OS and b) it is inconvenient to boot to the backup.

A Host or Parent OS that allows me to switch to a previous snapshot would be ideal. How can I accomplish this?

I know it is possible to do this by running a Virtual Machine, so that the Host can continuously run and manage the filesystem/backups; but I'm looking for the most efficient solution, and regular virtual machine might give extra overhead/lag?

Comment: The only way I know to do this is with commercial software. I have used both Norton Ghost and Paragon Backup & Recovery: both work well and neither is expensive, but you will need to overwrite your current system disc in order to recover, though you can do another back-up before you do if you need to keep the latest system in order to extract updated non-corrupt files from it.